# How to dynamically select drools rules for execution at business rule task level?

Tags: drools, drools-flow, redhat-brms

I've few drools rules that I want to use in different rule flows. Since, Drools rule supports only one ruleflow-group name at a time and rule flow business rule task also can be mapped with single ruleflow-group, I'm not able to use same rule in different rule flows. Is there any other way that I can use to filter the rules? like using tags or and metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own rule groups. You create a class OwnRuleGroup with String group in it as a field. Then when you fire rules you create an instance of your own rule grup:

```
OwnRuleGroup myGroup = new OwnRuleGroup();
myGroup.group = "foo";
```

and insert it into session with other facts. In every rule you could specify which of the groups you want to fire.

```
rule "This will fire for groups foo,bar"
when 
  OwnRuleGroup(group in ["foo", "bar"])
```